What is "Store Value" in gala games inventory?
I had bought an NFT from Mirandus game (gala games) long before. Now I opened my account to see the below in the gala games inventory, under Mirandus :

What does this store value mean? Is it the gala coins or something else?
I have the following two options to select from:

I really dont understand what to do here? Is the store value redeemable? Or is it possible to sell this NFT?
I tried to get an answer from google search and youtube search but couldnt find any answer. If someone can please help me, that would be much appreciated..

In their official site (https://gala.com/) you can find their discord and telegram. I suggest to enter those communications channels and ask there. It is a specific question better addressed by their community.
